# MPI vs. Microsoft WCF vs. Microsoft TPL

Tags: wcf, f#, mpi, task-parallel-library

I have a scientific program written in F# which I want to parallelize and run on 1 server with multiple processors (64) and for the future also in the cloud (Windows Azure?). The program will have a simple 1-1 communication between the nodes (no broadcast etc.).

If I used WCF, would it be as fast as MPI? What has MPI that WCF does not? There exists Pure MPI .NET written for WCF which puzzles me even more. I do not know if to use WCF or MPI.NET or Pure Mpi running on WCF.

PS: I guess that TPL is out of the game for 64 processors and more, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to give a concrete answer, because it all depends on the specific aspects of your application, its current architecture (I suppose you already have some app) etc.

- As you mention MPI and WCF, I assume that the application is written as several components that communicate with each other. The best way to structure this kind of application is to use **F# agents**. 
  As far as I understand, you want to run the application on a single server first. If you write it using agents, the agents can just communicate directly with each other (so you don't need MPI or WCF).
- **TPL** should work well on a single-server (with lots of CPUs), but it will not scale to the distributed setting - you cannot run `Task` on another machine. However, you can use it inside individual components (e.g. agents) that will be distributed.

Regarding MPI vs. WCF - I don't have enough experience to answer that. However, if you use agent-based architecture, it should be easy to try various options. You may also check out [fracture](https://github.com/fractureio/fracture) and related projects, which aims to implement high-performance sockets for F# (and possibly distributed agents in the future).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the F# Agents. I will study them during the weekend :).

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing it on 1 server you could just execute one process and execute the code in parallel. That way you could share memory more easily and faster than doing it through messages like MPI and WCF. Although the overhead of communication might not be that much, depending on your problem + solution.

Also the changes to your code would be much less that way, F# can usually be turned into prallel code with little effort. Going to MPI/WCF would require you to rewrite large portions.

Googling for F# + parallel gives plenty useful info that you should read first, like this for a good start:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/01/09/async-and-parallel-design-patterns-in-f-parallelizing-cpu-and-i-o-computations.aspx

So on 1 server, I woudl use the parallel features of F#, it's designed to prallelize easily.

Later when you want to go for cloud, that would be turning it into cleint-server. That's a different problem then parallization. I would treat  and solve them seperately.

On the MPI vs WCF. WCF is designed  as a RPC technology, i.e. you call remote procedures and get answers. If you want to use it for parallel programming with separate processes, you would have to create the boilerplate code for that. (Keep track of subsribed clients etc.)

MPI was designed to run that kind of architecture and handles it much more easily. (the first process gets number 0 and is the master, the other are slaves get numbered incrementally etc.)

Howver I don't think MPI will be very good to go cloud, since that invloves http, protocols, security etc. Not sure how well MPI works for those kind of things, WCF will handle that very well indeed.

The fact that there is an MPI.NET for WCF is because MPI is about a certain style of parallizing code that a lot of people are familiar with. So you can use the programming concepts and use them on the .NET platform leveraging WCF for the communications.

Something else you might want to look into if you need to exchange a lot of data over the wire is protocol-buffers (see [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) for instance). That can easily be combined with WCF for communication and is very lean in serializing structured data so you can send over the wire efficiently.

Gert-Jan

Answer (score 1):

WCF and MPI are different concepts. WCF is like a person A asks a person B to do something where as MPI is like a person A creates clones of himself (all clone have same ability/logic) and then these clones work on specific parts of the problem to be solved and once done they combine their results.

So choosing between which one fits your specific application depends on the problem your application is trying to solve. It may even be a combination of both WCF and MPI. Where your client application asks the WCF to do some task and the WCF create clones of the "problem solver" using MPI and when the clone are done with solving the problem (in parallel) they return the aggregated result back to the WCF and then that result is sent to client application.

Comment: I disagree with your definition of [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface#Overview). In simple words I would define it as an efficient communication protocol between components that can be distributed across different machines with different OSs and can be written in different languages.

Comment: My definition was more related to how the program written in MPI.NET works

Comment: I also disagree. You describe a particular programming style often associated with MPI. It is also quite possible to use MPI as a fast transport used by communicating sequential processes. I have prototyped a simple pub/sub layer on top of MPI.net - can achieve throughput of > 1M 32byte messages/sec sent A -> B -> C.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take at the 'mbrace' product, which provides a cloud monad (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/08/23/m-brace-f-in-the-cloud.aspx). It's still at a fairly early stage though.  I'm no expert but it may be that you can run an mbrace-based solution as effectively a private cloud on your 64-processor setup.  When you outgrow that, a move to Azure would be seamless.

Comment: The MBrace definitely sounds interesting but unfortunately it is still not for download.